# casting clone() in java

Tags: java, calendar, clone

so I have the following in my book:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2013,2,1);
Calendar calendar1 = (Calendar)calendar.clone();
```

Why is there the need for the casting `(Calendar)` ? isn't the `calendar.clone()` returning a `GregorianCalendar` copy of `calendar` ? if I delete the casting it's a compile error but if I write `System.out.println(calendar.clone().getClass());` it prints `GregorianCalendar`. Isn't `calendar1` pointing to a `GregorianCalendar` after `calendar.clone()` (without casting)?

Comment: from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29)  One disadvantage with the design of the clone() method is that the return type of clone() is Object, and needs to be explicitly cast back into the appropriate type. However, overriding clone() to return the appropriate type is preferable and eliminates the need for casting in the client (using covariant return types, since J2SE 5.0).

Comment: General comment about compile-time vs. run-time types: If you say `MyClass x = something` or `public MyClass method()`, the variable or function result can be `MyClass` or any of its subclasses, but the compiler is only allowed to know that it's `MyClass`.  So if you say `SubClass y = x`, the compiler rejects it because it doesn't know whether `x` is a `SubClass` or not.  It doesn't matter that `x` might be a `SubClass` when you run it.  If you say `SubClass y = (SubClass)x`, it will compile, and the program will check at run-time that `x` is a `SubClass`.

Comment: @ajb yes, I understand that, but it's not my case because GregorianCalendar is a subclass of Calendar, and if I do System.out.print(calendar.clone().getClass()) it says that the clone is a GregorianCalendar, and a Calendar can hold a reference to a GregorianCalendar; if I write Calendar calendar1 = (GregorianCalendar)calendar.clone(); it's still a valid expresion and I don't get an error. So why the explicit casting ?

Comment: @PopTudor What you see with `getClass()` is the **run-time type**.  Run-time types don't matter to the compiler because it can't predict what the run-time type will be.  As far as it knows, the result of `clone()` is an `Object`.  The fact that is is `GregorianCalendar` when you run it **does not matter at all** to the compiler.  You can assign `calendar1 =` to be a `GregorianCalendar` because all `GregorianCalendar`s are `Calendar`s.  But not all `Object`s are `Calendar`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clone()` returns an `Object`. That's why you need to cast it to `Calendar` (the compiler doesn't know that the actual returned instance is of type `Calendar`).

In general, you can't assign the return value of a method that returns `X` to a variable which is a sub-class of `X`.

```
/**
 * Creates and returns a copy of this object.
 *
 * @return a copy of this object.
 */
public Object clone() {}
```

As to the reason why it returns `Object`, `Calendar` has sub classes that override the `clone` method. Therefore they must all return the same type.

Comment: I think that they could have made `clone` return the individual types, because of covariance.  But covariance wasn't added to Java until later.

Comment: well isn't it returning an GregorianCalendar ? in System.out.print(calendar.clone().getClass()); it says that it's a GregorianCalendar returned not an Object

Comment: @PopTudor There's a difference between the type a method declares as its return type and the actual type of the object returned by it in a specific method call (which is only known at runtime). The compiler knows only about the former, and can't make decisions based on the latter.